# Cleansing company names with regex

Tags: regex, postgresql, replace, pattern-matching

I have a dataset (postgresql) with a field containing comma separated company names. Most company names are composed of regular characters (alphanumeric + space), but then there are some with a suffix such as ", inc." or ", ltd.". In order to split the the company names into separate strings, I need to remove the comma that is used to signal the company name suffixes first (and that is an external requirement). So, for instance in

> Burn To Ground, Groupwise, Ltd., People, Inc., SepiaShot

my regex should be able to remove the 2nd and the 4th commas, but not the other ones. I would like to know if this can be done using regex. I have tried several solutions using balanced groups and look-arounds, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: only possible if you have specific set of words which can act as permitted suffixes. Here you have Ltd. and Inc. Words other than these ?

Comment: This is yet another example of http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788 and related, i.e. "don't store comma delimited text in a database".

Comment: For the record: I don't either. This is some data that has been previously crawled from the older version of a website. For one thing, I will try to avoid arrays in a RDBM all together from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this regex:

```
\,(?=\s(?:Ltd|Inc))
```

I assume you want to remove the commas before these words only, if you have more words like corp. reg. etc you can add them in the regex with a `|` like this

```
\,(?=\s(?:Ltd|Inc|Corp|Reg))
```

modify this regex according to your requirement

here is the demo for a quick reference:

http://regex101.com/r/rT5zB1

check the substitution result

Comment: I'm not sure Pg's regular expression processor supports assertions.

Comment: it supports ! more here : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Excellent! I slightly modified the regex and used this: 

`update companies set names = regexp_replace(names,'\,(?=\s?(?:AB|AG|SA|SARL|GMBH|BVBA|Ltée|LLP|II|Ltd|Inc|Corp)\M)','','ig')`

Answer (score 4):

Aelor was close, but used a positive rather than a negative assertion and didn't handle the space. (Actually, per comment, Aelor answered the specific question posed; I'm showing how to avoid removing the commas entirely by ignoring them when splitting).

Also added a comprehensive list of company name suffixes from [corporateinformation.com](http://www.corporateinformation.com/Company-Extensions-Security-Identifiers.aspx).

```
regress=> SELECT regexp_split_to_table(
            'Burn To Ground, Groupwise, Ltd., People, Inc., SepiaShot', 
            '\,(?!\s(?:A\. en P\.|AB|AB|A\.C\.|ACE|AD|AE|AG|AG|AG|AL|AmbA|ANS|Apb|ApS|ApS & Co\. K/S|AS|A/S|A\.S\.|A\.S\.|A\.S\.|A\.S\.|ASA|AVV|Bpk|Bt|B\.V\.|B\.V\.|B\.V\.|BVBA|CA|Corp\.|C\.V\.|CVA|CVoA|DA|d/b/a|d\.d\.|d\.d\.|d\.n\.o\.|d\.o\.o\.|d\.o\.o\.|EE|EEG|EIRL|ELP|EOOD|EPE|EURL|e\.V\.|GbR|GCV|GesmbH|GIE|GmbH & Co\. KG|GmbH|GmbH|GmbH|HB|hf|IBC|Inc\.|Inc|I/S|j\.t\.d\.|KA/S|Kb|Kb|KD|k\.d\.|k\.d\.|KDA|k\.d\.d\.|Kft|KG|KG|KGaA|KK|Kkt|Kol\. SrK|Kom\. SrK|k\.s\.|K/S|KS|Kv|Ky|Lda|LDC|LLC|LLP|Ltd\.|Ltda|Ltée\.|N\.A\.|NT|NV|NV|NV|NV|OE|OHG|OHG|OOD|OÜ|Oy|OYJ|P/L|PC Ltd|PLC|PMA|PMDN|PrC|Prp\. Ltd\.|PT|Pty\.|RAS|Rt|S\. de R\.L\.|S\. en C\.|S\. en N\.C\.|S/A|SA|SA|SA|sa|SA|SA|SA|SA|SA|SA|SA|S\.A\.|SA de CV|SAFI|S\.A\.I\.C\.A\.|SApA|Sarl|Sarl|SAS|SC|SC|S\.C\.|SCA|SCA|SCP|SCS|S\.C\.S\.|SCS|Sdn Bhd|SENC|SGPS|SK|SNC|SNC|SNC|SNC|SOPARFI|sp|SpA|spol s\.r\.o\.|SPRL|Sp\. z\.o\.o\.|Srl|Srl|Srl|Srl|Srl|td|TLS|VEB|VOF|v\.o\.s\.)) ?',
            'i'
          );
 regexp_split_to_table 
-----------------------
 Burn To Ground
 Groupwise, Ltd.
 People, Inc.
 SepiaShot
(4 rows)
```

Tested on PostgreSQL 9.3.

Consider non-USA company suffixes too, e.g. the german "GMBH". I strongly recommend that you treat the results of your substitution as suspect, and get a human to verify that they are correct.

Comment: you have done the opposite lol. The op wants to remove the `2nd and the 4th commas not the other ones` you have removed the rest apart from 2nd and 4th :)

Comment: No, I've just solved the whole problem, by splitting the strings *without* stripping the commas. They don't *need* to remove the commas, just ignore them for the purpose of the string splitting pattern expression.

Comment: Great job! I can't use this right now, because I really have to remove those commas (not really my choice). But hopefully in a later version I can keep them. I save the reference! Btw, that's an impressive list of suffixes you have compiled.